# Indexing and then searching within date ranges using cfindex and cfsearch

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-2016

Using ColdFusion 2016, does anyone know if its possible to include a date when using `cfindex`, and then search within date ranges using `cfsearch`? So I could index documents, including their upload date to the collection, and then say search only documents uploaded in 2019?

*edit*

I've managed to get a date into the collection, using a custom field of type `date/_dt`. Now how to search it ...

Comment: Can you provide an example of the code you're working with?

Comment: I don't know if you figured it out, but here's what worked for me in CF2018 https://stackoverflow.com/a/57131685/8895292