# How to pass a date into a ColdFusion collection to be searched

Tags: date, collections, solr, coldfusion

I'm using a ColdFusion collection to search events and I need to pass a date into the collection as a "mmm" so it can be searched. Every time I try I get an error.

```
custom4="DateFormat(start_date, "mmm")"
```

**Update:**
I'm trying to search "month" of the current year

Comment: What version of CF? Also, is start_date a query column?

Comment: Do you have a screenshot of the error?

Comment: What is your surrounding code? Can you provide more context around what you are trying to do? What does your data look like? What sort of collection are you searching? You are just trying to find dates that happened in a given month?

Answer (score 1):

You should use the above code like

```
custom4=dateFormat(start_date, "mmm")
```

(Remove the outer double quotes)

Comment: I tried this but it causes me an error when i create run the collection. There must be some way of formatting a date in a coldfusion verity collection right?

Comment: No, dateFormat() can't be applied to that attribute when it's a query column.

Comment: Is there a way of formatting a date when you create a collection?

Comment: What is the source of start_date? If it is a query, format it in the sql. Though it also depends on how you'll be searching the collection. As asked above , will you be searching for dates in a specific month and year?

Comment: @Arun - If you test the code above, it throws an error

Answer (score 0):

Quotes aren't the problem and [the suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57039481/8895292) of removing them will actually **cause** an error. The problem is [DateFormat()](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-c-d/DateFormat.html) can't be applied to an entire query column. It's only capable of operating on a single value.

It would help to have more context about what you're trying to achieve, to determine the best approach.

- If you want to find items dated in July of a *specific* year (i.e. July 2019) - then storing the full date, and searching for a date range, is probably a better way to go
- If you want to find items dated in July of ANY year, then it's simpler to extract a month *number* within your SQL query, and store it in the collection. Then you need only search for a number.

---

#### Date Range Search

To search for a specific month/year, like July 2019, populate the collection with a timestamp field from your SQL query. Add the suffix `_dt` to the custom field name so it's treated as a date field

```
    cfindex( query="yourQuery"
            , collection="yourCollection"
            , action="Update"
            , type="Custom"
            , Start_Date_dt="yourTimeStampColumn"
            , ...
    );
```

In the search criteria, use the date range July 1 through August 1, 2019 (yes - *August* 1st). Dates must be formatted for Solr, which expects [`YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ssZ`](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/working-with-dates.html). *NB: Dates should be in UTC (**not local time**).*

```
cfsearch (name="searchResults"
    , collection="yourCollection"
    , criteria=' start_date_dt:[2019-07-01T04:00:00Z TO 2019-08-01T04:00:00Z}' 
);
```

*Explanation/Notes*

- `[` and `}` - Brackets indicates a range (i.e. from dateX TO dateY)
- `[` - Square bracket means inclusive (i.e. include July 1st)
- `}` - Curly bracket means exclusive (i.e. exclude August 1st)
- Field names should be in lower case

---

#### Month Number Search

To search for a specific month in *any year*, like July, extract the month number within your SQL query. (The exact syntax will be DBMS specific. You didn't mention which one you're using, so see your database's documentation on date functions.) Add the suffix `_i` to the custom field name so it's handled as an integer

```
    cfindex( query="yourQuery"
            , collection="yourCollection"
            , action="Update"
            , type="Custom"
            , monthNumber_i="theMonthNumberColumn"
            , ...
    );
```

Then simply search for the desired month number, i.e. 7 - July

```
cfsearch ( name="searchResults"
            , collection="yourCollection"
            , criteria=' monthnumber_i:7 '
    );
```

---

#### Full Example

**Sample Query**

```
sampleData = queryNew("MyID,Start_Date,MonthNumber"
    , "integer,timestamp,integer"
    , [{MyID=10, Start_Date="2019-06-30 12:30:00", MonthNumber=6}
    , {MyID=20, Start_Date="2019-07-01 00:00:00", MonthNumber=7}
    , {MyID=30, Start_Date="2019-07-01 16:30:00", MonthNumber=7}
    , {MyID=40, Start_Date="2019-07-31 23:50:00", MonthNumber=7}
    , {MyID=50, Start_Date="2019-08-01 00:00:00", MonthNumber=8}
]);
```

**Create Collection**

```
cfcollection ( action="create", collection="MyCollection");
```

**Update Collection**

```
cfindex( query="sampleData"
        , collection="MyCollection"
        , action="Update"
        , type="Custom"
        , key="MyID"
        , title="SampleData"
        , MonthNumber_i="MonthNumber"
        , Start_Date_dt="Start_Date"
        , body="MyID"
);
```

**Find July, by month number**

```
cfsearch ( name="monthNumberResults"
            , collection="MyCollection"
            , criteria=' monthnumber_i:7 '
        );

// results 
writeDump( var=monthNumberResults, label="Month Number Search" );
```

**Find July 2019, by date range**

```
// Search range: July 1 to August 1, 2019
fromDate = "2019-07-01";
toDate   = dateAdd("m", 1, fromDate);

// Format dates for Solr
// Note: DateTimeFormat uses "n" for minutes. Valid in CF2016 Update 3 or higher
fromDate = dateTimeFormat( dateConvert("local2UTC", fromDate), "yyyy-mm-dd'T'HH:nn:ss'Z'");
toDate   = dateTimeFormat( dateConvert("local2UTC", toDate), "yyyy-mm-dd'T'HH:nn:ss'Z'");

cfsearch ( name="dateRangeResults"
            , collection="MyCollection"
            , criteria=' start_date_dt:[#fromDate# TO #toDate#} '
        );

// results 
writeDump( var=dateRangeResults, label="Date Range Search" );
```

Comment: This pretty much answered my question. Thanks for all your help guys.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what were you trying to do - find "July" of any year or only a specific year?

Comment: I was trying to search "month" of the current year.